# The WebBrowser very slow in server from the second times calling

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I call the  NavigateFromBrowser() first time, it return very fast, however if I called it again, it is very Slowly, and finally timeout. BTW, this issue just happens in the Windows server, and doesn't happen in Windows Client such as win7.Please advice why this happens.

```
private void NavigateFromBrowser()
 {
  using (var wb = new WebBrowser())
   {
                    wb.Width = Width;
                    wb.Height = Height;
                    wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                    wb.Navigate(_url);

                    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }

   }
}
```

Comment: How do you call it again? In code, just 2 lines after each other? Or by refreshing the page, or ...?

Comment: From your profile I notice that you do not accept answers. Please, to mark a question as solved, click on the grey checkmark which is available on answers. This will make the checkmark green and we know that your question has been solved.